# Simplifying development process for Django

Tags: python, django, git, web-deployment

I'm a freelance editor and tutor as well as a fiction writer and artist looking to transition to the latter on a full-time basis. Naturally, part of that transition involves constructing a website; a dynamic site to which new content in various forms can be added with ease. Now, I've always intended to learn how to program, and I simply haven't the money to hire someone else to do it. So, having had a good experience with my brief dabblings in Python, I decided I'd go with Django for building my site.

I set up a Fedora Virtualbox for a development environment (as I didn't want to jump through hoops to make Windows work) and went to town on some Django tutorials. Everything went swimmingly until life intervened and I didn't touch the project for three weeks. I'm in a position to return to it now, but I've realized two things in the process. First, I'm having to do a fair bit of retracing of my steps just to find where certain files are, and second, I don't know how I'd go about deploying the site after I'm done building it. My intention is to get the cheapest Linode and host off that until some theoretical point in the future where I required more.

I suspect that re: the file organization issue, that's just something I'll become more familiar with over time, though if there are any tricks I should be aware of to simplify the structure of my overall Django development space, I'm eager to know them. However, what about deployment? How viable is it to, with sufficient knowledge, automate the process of pushing the whole file structure of a site with Git? And how can I do that in such a way that it doesn't tamper with the settings of my development environment?

Answer (score 0):

As a Django developer i can assure you that it grows on you and becomes easier to understand the development environment.

1. You should remember that settings.py is probably going to be where your thoughts will be for quite a while in the start; the good part is that its only once, after you got it up and running you'll only touch settings.py to add new modules or change some configuration but its unlikely.
2. I believe there are hosts that integrate with git so that should not be a problem since you will probably just git clone your project's url into the host (and not forget to enable/configure wsgi)
3. To leave the settings.py out of the mess, you will tell git not to track the file with: git rm file; and then when you add your files for commit you do it with git add -u so it refers only to your tracked files.

I'm not sure if i was clear enough. (probably not) But, i hope i could help you in some way.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Concerning the second point; when you say 'integrate with git,' how does that manifest functionally? Keep in mind that I only started investigating Git seriously this evening. Thanks in advance.